# Show form fields only if information not already in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to only display form parameters as input fields if you don't already have the information somewhere else (e.g. from the user session)?

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, Message.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Name: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: "E-mail: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
    <%= f.input :message_text, label: "Message: " %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message" %>
 </p>
```

I'd effectively like it to show "name" if the person filling in the form is NOT currently signed in, and be pre-populated with the user's "firstname lastname" from the database if they are.

Same for e-mail address.

The recipient of the message should receive either the form elements or the pre-populated elements, depending on which is relevant.

Is this something that happens in the form view or MessagesController?

ADDED: I've also defined message_params below this which is called in the 'create' method:

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :message_text, :subject, :is_read, :user_id)
end
```

Could this have an impact?

Comment: So you *still* want to show the form fields in both cases -- when the user is signed in **and** when he isn't. You just want them to display the user's data in the former scenario. Your question could use some clearing up.

Comment: yes - that's right. I'd still like to show the form fields if the user is signed in, just with pre-populated user information when signed in. Thanks! Sorry - first question. Total newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this with a little help. Added to messages controller:

```
def new
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
@message = Message.new

if current_user.present?
  @message.name = current_user.name
  @message.email = current_user.email
end  
# display form for 'new' message

end
```

added to user model:

```
def name
    "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
end
```

amended view for new message:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @message] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name, label: "Name: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
<%= f.input :email, label: "E-mail: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
<%= f.input :subject, label: "Subject: ", input_html: {size:100} %>
<%= f.input :message_text, label: "Message: " %>

 <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the nudges in the right direction @Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
@user = current_user || User.new
```

Answer (score 0):

new action

```
def new    
    if current_user
      @message = Message.new(:email => current_user.email, :name => current_user.firstname + " " + current_user.lastname)
    else
      @message = Message.new
    end
end
```

view

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Name: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: "E-mail: ", input_html: {size:50} %>
    <%= f.input :message_text, label: "Message: " %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message" %>
 </p>
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre - I tried this but the information doesn't seem to be appearing in the form. I've defined message_params below as def message_params
   params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :message_text, :subject, :is_read, :user_id)
  end - could this have something to do with it?

Comment: im not sure what might be the problem, your params seem to be correct. could you link to github ?